# MySQL avg() and count() in one statement with group by

Tags: mysql

today I'm fighting with MySQL: I've got two tables, that contain records like that (actually there are more columns, but I don't think it's relevant):

Table Metering:

```
id, value
1000, 0.117
1000, 0.689
1001, 0.050
...
```

Table Res (there is no more than one record per id in this table):

```
id, number_residents
1001, 2
...
```

I try to get results in the following format:

```
number_residents, avg, count(id)
2, 0.1234, 456
3, 0.5678, 567
...
```

In words: I try to find out the average of the *value*-fields with the same number_residents. The *id*-field is the connection between the two tables. The *count(id)*-column should show how many ids have been found with that number_residents. The query I could come up with was the following:

```
select number_residents,count(distinct Metering.id),avg(value)
  from Metering, Res
  where Metering.id = Res.id
  group by number_residents;
```

The results look like what I searched for but when I tried to validate them I became insecure. I tried it without the *distinct* at first but that leads to too high values in the count-column of the results.
Is my statement right to get what I want? I thought it might have to to something with the order of execution like asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127932/mysql-query-clause-execution-order), but I actually can't find any official documentation on that...

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Your query is quite well-defined, so the order of execution has no bearing on the results. You should learn proper `join` syntax. But, the issue is: What results do you want? Are there duplicates in `Res`? You need to edit your question with *expected* results as well as sample data. The statement "the average value of all ids" is ambiguous, because you have multiple rows with the same id. How should those be handled?

Comment: Ok, I indeed didn't mention that there are no duplicates in Res. I edited the question.
And thanks for the hint on the ambiguous value of all ids. My head was kind of too full yesterday. Edited the question too!

Comment: But for the _expected_ results I'm not sure what you mean... The only real result is the avg column and what I expect is something in the range of 0 to 5 but I don't see why that should be important.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the table names, `Res` is the "parent" table and `Metering` us the "child" table - that is there are 0-n meterings for each residence.

You have use "old school" joins (and I mean *old* - the join syntax has been around for 25 years now), which are *inner* joins, meaning residences *without* meterings won't participate in the results.

Use an *outer* join:

```
select
    number_residents,
    count(distinct r.id) residences_count,
    avg(value) average_value
from Res r
left join Metering m on m.id = r.id
group by number_residents
```

Although meterings.id = res.id, with a *left* join counting them may produce different results: I've changed the count to count *residences*, which for a *left* join means residences that don't have meterings still count.

Now, nulls (which are what you get from a left-joined table that doesn't have a matching row) don't participate in `avg()` - either for the numerator or denominator, if you want residences without any meterings to count when calcukating the average (as if they have a single zero metering for the purposes of dividing the total value), use this query:

```
select
    number_residents,
    count(distinct r.id) residences_count,
    sum(value) / count(r.id) average_value
from Res r
left join Metering m on m.id = r.id
group by number_residents
```

Because res.id is never null, `count(r.id)` counts the number of meterings plus 1 for every residence without any meterings.