# MySQL Syntax ERROR on WHERE select

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make multiple table select where ID = variabile.

Example code is below, I belieave it should work but somehow I have some error in Syntax.

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstname, c.surname, c.email, c.process, c.search_work, c.note,
 group_concat(DISTINCT ce.enforcement) as enfor, 
 group_concat(DISTINCT cc.city) as city
FROM candidates AS c
LEFT JOIN candidates_language AS cl ON c.id = cl.candidates_id
LEFT JOIN candidates_enforcement as ce on c.id = ce.candidates_id
LEFT JOIN candidates_city as cc on c.id = cc.candidates_id
GROUP BY c.id, c.firstname, c.surname, c.email 
WHERE c.id='8'
```

Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25b1b/24

ERROR:
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id='

Please is there a chance someone can navigate me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: WHERE needs to be before youre GROUP BY statement :) WHERE is always before the group by as it filters the data before it is grouped. You can use HAVING after the group by to do the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mismatched the location between `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` clause. `WHERE` clause should always come before `GROUP BY` clause since `WHERE` clause will filter the dataset based on the condition and on that filtered data set the grouping or `GROUP BY` is going to happen. So in your query it should be

```
WHERE c.id='8'
GROUP BY c.id, c.firstname, c.surname, c.email
```

Comment: Hey Rahul, thank you for answer it is correct of course and you got THUMB UP for it from me. Unfortuantely Nighthunter22 was first so to be fair I mark his answer :)
Thanks for understanding

Comment: @Andurit Being first does not always imply a higher quality answer. Personally, I think Rahul's answer does a better job of explaining the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you looking for:

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstname, c.surname, c.email, c.process, c.search_work, c.note,
 group_concat(DISTINCT ce.enforcement) as enfor, 
 group_concat(DISTINCT cc.city) as city
FROM candidates AS c
LEFT JOIN candidates_language AS cl ON c.id = cl.candidates_id
LEFT JOIN candidates_enforcement as ce on c.id = ce.candidates_id
LEFT JOIN candidates_city as cc on c.id = cc.candidates_id
WHERE c.id='8' --where comes before the group by
GROUP BY c.id, c.firstname, c.surname, c.email;
```

Comment: Ouch, that simple? THANKS

Comment: yea, actualy jsut waiting until it let me do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because there `WHERE` clause should come before the `GROUP BY` clause, as others have mentioned. I would also like to add reference to the documentation for the [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) syntax, which shows the order of clauses for the statement. I've summarized the order for you, and put brackets around the optional clauses:

```
SELECT
FROM
[WHERE]
[GROUP BY]
[HAVING]
[ORDER BY]
[LIMIT]
```

---

On a side note, the order that clauses are executed is not the same as they are written. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127932/mysql-query-clause-execution-order), for more information on that.