# php jquery showing data from mysql getjson

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, getjson

I need to show data retrieved from mysql in a page. My codes are :

jquery:

```
$('#search').on('click', function() { 
        alert($('.search_word').val());
        var data_to_php = $('.search_name:visible').val(); //take the text only from the visible search box
        alert(data_to_php);


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //The following code will get the search list populated  by //////////
        //retrieving data from mysql table////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        $.getJSON('./search.php', 'keyword='+data_to_php, function(info) {

                $.each(info, function() {
                    $('ul.search_list').append('<li   class="search_data">hi</li>'); //this code is for the purpose of testing only

                    console.log(info);
                }); 


        });

    }); //end #search.on.click
```

the php code is :

```
require(connect.php);

$keywords = $_GET['keyword'];

$query = "SELECT name FROM test ORDER BY name WHERE name LIKE   '%".$_GET['keyword']."%'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query); //connection variable
                                      //$conn is from
                                      //included file
                                      //connect.php 

$jsonData = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $jsonData[] = $row;

}

echo json_encode($jsonData);
?>
```

In `console.log` output, I am getting :

> GET ./search.php?keyword=s 500 Internal Server Error with blank
>   response. Internal error 500 can as well be generated if php is not
>   working properly. There might also be some error in the code.

Now `phpinfo` is showing results properly.

How do I know if the getjson call to php script is successful?

Comment: What happens when you try to access ./search.php?keyword=s just in the browser? Do you still get error 500?

Comment: yes - with server error 500, it is showing : The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/autocomplete/search.php?keyword=s. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Comment: what do you get on var_dump($jsonData); ??

Comment: how do I see the content of var_dump?

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in your MySQL query, you cannot call ORDER BY before WHERE clause, modify your query,

`SELECT name FROM test WHERE name LIKE '%".$_GET['keyword']."%' ORDER BY name`

A very good reference to know the correct order of execution in MySQL - [MySQL query / clause execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127932/mysql-query-clause-execution-order)

Also, your file name in the require function should be enclosed within quotes - `require('connect.php');`

Comment: Thnk you for pointing out the error. But unfortunately the same error is showing up ....!! I did not forget to restart apache though ....

Comment: Did you check your Mysql connection ? what do you have in connect.php ?

Comment: it is : define('DB_SERVER', "localhost");
define('DB_USER', "root");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "");
define('DB_TABLE', "test_php");

$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_TABLE);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
} but connection error does not show either

Comment: that looks alright, hope you have the credentials right though...since you're getting a 500 error it has to be on your Server side,

Comment: I think your require is causing the problem, modify it like this `require("connect.php");` it should be enclosed within quotes