# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 in sql select statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I've just started to learn PHP. What I am trying to do a very simple sql select statement-

```
<?php
    $sql = 'SELECT firstname, lastname,email
           FROM MyGuests
          ORDER BY firstname where id=12';
?>
```

It gives the following error-

> Could not connect to the database testdb :SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Sorry if it's a foolish question.

Comment: The WHERE clause (WHERE id=12) should go before ORDER BY

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob,  Post it as an answer.

Comment: @s.k.paul You have three answers stating the same thing already (two of which were posted within the same minute of that comment, so were probably being typed as that was)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is in the wrong order, `order by` needs to be after the `where`.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname,email
           FROM MyGuests
          where id=12
ORDER BY firstname
```

You can see the order for all functions in the manual, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html.

Answer (score 2):

Switch the `ORDER BY` and `WHERE` clauses:

```
SELECT firstname,
       lastname,
       email
FROM MyGuests
WHERE id = 12
ORDER BY firstname
```

Here is a useful Stack Overflow question which lists the order of interpretation of a MySQL statement:

[MySQL query / clause execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127932/mysql-query-clause-execution-order)

Answer (score 1):

You got the syntax wrong..

```
SELECT..
FROM..
WHERE..
GROUP BY..
ORDER BY ..
```

So:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname,email
FROM MyGuests
where id=12
ORDER BY firstname
```