# puzzled by the evaluation order in mysql

Tags: mysql, logical-operators, partition

I tried to write my own window function in mysql but found something I don't understand as shown below.

The table employee has 13 rows,

```
+----+------+--------+
| id | name | salary |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | a    |    123 |
|  2 | a    |    234 |
|  4 | a    |    254 |
|  8 | a    |    724 |
|  9 | a    |    432 |
| 12 | a    |    123 |
|  3 | b    |    124 |
| 10 | b    |    333 |
| 11 | b    |     11 |
| 13 | b    |    628 |
|  5 | c    |    111 |
|  6 | c    |    777 |
|  7 | c    |    666 |
+----+------+--------+
```

So if I use the following query,

```
select name, salary, 
      (case name when @prev_name  then  @rank := @rank + 1
       else @prev_name := name and @rank := 1 end) + 1 as Rank
from employee , (select @rank := 0,  @prev_name := null ) r  
order by name ;
```

The results are

```
+------+--------+------+
| name | salary | Rank |
+------+--------+------+
| a    |    123 |    1 |
| a    |    234 |    2 |
| a    |    254 |    3 |
| a    |    724 |    4 |
| a    |    432 |    5 |
| a    |    123 |    6 |
| b    |    124 |    7 |
| b    |    333 |    8 |
| b    |     11 |    9 |
| b    |    628 |   10 |
| c    |    111 |   11 |
| c    |    777 |   12 |
| c    |    666 |   13 |
+------+--------+------+
```

with 14 warnings,

```
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                            |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'b                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'b                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'b                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'b                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'c                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'c                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'c                             ' |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But if I change the order inside the `else` clause,

```
select name, salary, 
      (case name when @prev_name  then  @rank := @rank + 1
       else @rank := 1 and @prev_name := name end) + 1 as Rank
from employee , (select @rank := 0,  @prev_name := null ) r  
order by name ;
```

The output is different,

```
+------+--------+------+
| name | salary | Rank |
+------+--------+------+
| a    |    123 |    1 |
| a    |    234 |    2 |
| a    |    254 |    3 |
| a    |    724 |    4 |
| a    |    432 |    5 |
| a    |    123 |    6 |
| b    |    124 |    1 |
| b    |    333 |    2 |
| b    |     11 |    3 |
| b    |    628 |    4 |
| c    |    111 |    1 |
| c    |    777 |    2 |
| c    |    666 |    3 |
+------+--------+------+
```

without warnings.

My guess is that is related to logical operator short-cut and the return value of the assignment operator. But I could not found any useful information online.

This becomes even more interesting after I tried different ways.

So the following query gives totally different results sometimes,

```
set @prev_name := null; set @rank := 0; 
select name, salary, 
       (case name when @prev_name  then  @rank := @rank + 1 else @prev_name := name and @rank := 1 end) + 1 as Rank
from employee order by name ;

+------+--------+------+
| name | salary | Rank |
+------+--------+------+
| a    |    123 |    1 |
| a    |    234 |    1 |
| a    |    254 |    1 |
| a    |    724 |    1 |
| a    |    432 |    1 |
| a    |    123 |    1 |
| b    |    124 |    1 |
| b    |    333 |    1 |
| b    |     11 |    1 |
| b    |    628 |    1 |
| c    |    111 |    1 |
| c    |    777 |    1 |
| c    |    666 |    1 |
+------+--------+------+
```

With 13 warnings,

```
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                            |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'b                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'b                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'b                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'b                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'c                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'c                             ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'c                             ' |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I could not reproduce your first result with your first query.

Comment: The return value of an assignment is normally the value assigned. Your code doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: @trincot, that is one problem with that query, it is not deterministic.

Comment: @EJP, It does not make sense to me either. That is why I am asking here

Comment: What doesn't make sense is to AND the result of two assignments together using a short-cut operator and then express surprise because you get different results when you reverse the order, *unless* you are certain that both assignments yield `true` or both `false`. In the other cases your surprise has no rational basis.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have an explanation for what you are seeing.  Consider your first query, which is not generating row numbers per group as you intended:

```
select name, salary, 
      (case name when @prev_name  then  @rank := @rank + 1
       else @prev_name := name and @rank := 1 end) + 1 as Rank
from employee , (select @rank := 0,  @prev_name := null ) r  
order by name ;
```

I hypothesize that the assignments `@prev_name := name` *and* `@rank := 1` *both* return false.  If this were true, then the other part of the `else` condition would not need to evaluate, because of short-circuiting, since the outcome would already be known to be false.  In the case of your first query, this means that the assignment `@prev_name := name` would happen at each row.  If we also assume that the `@prev_name := null` assignment happens *before* this first assignment, then it would explain why the first result set is just a row number over the entire table.  This is the case because `@rank := @rank + 1` would occur for every row, over the entire table.  On the other hand, in your second query:

```
select name, salary, 
      (case name when @prev_name  then  @rank := @rank + 1
       else @rank := 1 and @prev_name := name end) + 1 as Rank
from employee , (select @rank := 0,  @prev_name := null ) r  
order by name ;
```

In this case, again `@rank := 1` returns false, but now the assignment to `@prev_name` does not happen.

But, I would not write the query you did, because it seems confusing to me.  Instead, I suggest that you use the following query:

```
SET @row_number = NULL;
SET @emp_name = NULL;

SELECT
    @row_number:=CASE WHEN @emp_name = name THEN @row_number + 1 ELSE 1 END AS Rank,
    @emp_name := name,
    salary
FROM employee
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: My questions is what is the return value of an assignment and what order of these expressions executed. But I could not find any docs

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your first result, but there are several things you should take into account:

- The order in which the `select` clause expressions are fed with records does not depend on the `order by` clause, since [the sorting only happens *after* all result records have been evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24128128/5459839). So even if all other logic is correct, the result can vary.
- The assignment (`:=`) operator has [the lowest priority](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html). This means `and` is executed before `:=`.
- As an assignment only makes sense when at the left it has a variable, this variable can never take part in another operation before the assignment happens. So this is a kind of exception to the normal precendence rules.
- For logical operators a short-cut evaluation is performed (not found in documentation).
- When string values take part in a logical operator, they are converted to boolean (0 or 1)

Taking these rules into account, see how the following evaluates:

```
@prev_name := name and @rank := 1
```

1. `and` has the highest precedence, so the argument at the left of it is evaluated first, this is the value of `name`
2. The value for `name` is converted to a boolean as it has to take part in a boolean operation. As in your sample data none of the names represent a valid number, this value is 0
3. As this is enough to know the result of the `and` operation, the right argument is *not* evaluated, and so the assignment `@rank := 1` is not performed.
4. Finally the left-most assignment is performed, and `@prev_name` gets value 0.

In your query this means the comparison `case name when @prev_name ...` could hardly ever be true: the first time it is not true because `@prev_name` is `null`, and after that it will always be 0. An exception to this would be if `name` has the value "0" or "1": in that case you will get a rank increase.

Now to the inverse expression:

```
@rank := 1 and @prev_name := name
```

The evaluation happens as follows:

1. `and` has the highest precedence, so the argument at the left of it is evaluated first, this is 1
2. As this is now not enough to know the result of the `and` operation, the right argument must be evaluated
3. As the right side is an assignment, that assignment must happen first, so at this moment `@prev_name` gets the value of `name`
4. For this value to partake in the boolean operation it is converted to a number, which most probably is 0 (see above): it will be 0 for the sample data you have given.
5. This makes the result of the `and` operation to be 0
6. Finally, this value (0) is assigned to `@rank`

In this scenario `@prev_name` gets a useful value, and if the recordset is traversed in the order we hope for, then indeed the rank will increase.

Another issue can surface because of this initialisation:

```
@prev_name := null
```

This does not tell MySql which datatype this variable has, and so it may decide it is of a numeric data type. This can lead to weird effects, where `@prev_name` stays `null` throughout the query, or takes on the character code of the first character in the `name` value.

#### Better approach

To better secure the order in which the records are fetched, you would need to fetch them in a sub-select, which you provide with the `order by` clause.

Only in the outer query you can then rely on a specific order of evaluation -- even though there is still no documented guarantee for that.

Initialise your variables with something that leaves no doubt about the data type, for instance:

```
@prev_name := ''
```

You can use the MySql `if` function for making assignments and at the same time return a value, like this:

```
if(a := b, value, value)
```

Whatever the assignment returns as boolean result, `if` will return *value*.

Taking all this together, I would suggest this query:

```
select name, salary, 
       @rank := if(name = @prev_name, @rank + 1, 
                   if(@prev_name := name, 1, 1)) as Rank
from   (select name, salary from employee order by name) employee,
       (select @rank := 0, @prev_name := '') init
order  by name;
```

## Final remark

Other databases have window/analytic/OLAP functions, which makes ranking a much more reliable task.