# Will a function will be recalled when I use its alias in ORDER BY clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Here is the simplified version of my query:

```
SELECT myfunc(u.id) score FROM users u
ORDER BY score
LIMIT 20
```

As you see, I've used `score` *(which is the result of `myfunc()` function)* in the `ORDER BY` clause. Now I want to know, will that function be recalled when I use it in `ORDER BY` clause? If yes, then how can I avoid that? Because that function needs lots of processing and recalling it twice would be like a nightmare.

Comment: No - ORDER BY is evaluated last: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127932/mysql-query-clause-execution-order) The query engine knows to wait to sort by the result of the function until it applies the function to each row.

Comment: On the other hand, `HAVING` does reevaluate.

Comment: Is it declared `DETERMINISTIC`?

Comment: @RickJames Honestly I don't know what's `DETERMINISTIC` .. what do you mean exactly by that?

Comment: Is your function a "Stored Proc"? or a "UDF"?

Comment: @RickJames no it is not a procedure. I don't use `CALL` to call it. I just use it into `select` statement.

Comment: I meant Stored Function.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, because the data has already been prepared by the time the ordering is done. If you still have a doubt, test it by making your function do something visible between runs (increment a value in a table)

What you may find though, is that it runs a million times, once for each of a million rows, before limit 20 can be applied..

If your function is really slow, and its sensible to store the result upon insert rather than calculate it every time the query is run, do that