# MYSQL: how to use virtual field in where using left join query?

Tags: mysql

I have to find user using age. But, **age** field not available in my **user_basic_info** table. I have one **dob** field in **user_basic_info** table. i have create virtual age field. but, i have return one error **"Unknown column 'age' in 'where clause'"**

My Query:

```
SELECT
    `users`.`nickname`,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,user_basic_info.dob,CURDATE()) AS `age`
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `user_basic_info`
    ON user_basic_info.user_id = users.id
WHERE
    (`users`.`status`=1) AND
    ((age >= 22) OR (age <= 30))
```

Comment: You can utilize alias of column in where clause because of sql execution behavior. Please answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127932/mysql-query-clause-execution-order. This is why you can utilize alias in group by , having and order by clause.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because the `age` alias is not available in the `WHERE` clause at the time when it is evaluated.  Your options include either repeating the expression for age in the `WHERE` clause (ugly) or doing a subquery to use the alias (potentially not performant).  For the purpose of readability I might do this:

```
SELECT
    nickname,
    age
FROM
(
    SELECT
        users.nickname,
        users.status,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, user_basic_info.dob, CURDATE()) AS age
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN user_basic_info
        ON user_basic_info.user_id = users.id
) t
WHERE
    status = 1 AND age BETWEEN 22 AND 30;
```

If you are performance-minded, then you can just repeat the expression for age in the `WHERE` clause of your original query:

```
SELECT
    users.nickname,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,user_basic_info.dob,CURDATE()) AS age
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_basic_info
    ON user_basic_info.user_id = users.id
WHERE
    user.status = 1 AND
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, user_basic_info.dob, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 22 AND 30;
```

Answer (score 1):

The second `Where` clause that references `age` should be moving to a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
    u.`nickname`,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,user_basic_info.dob,CURDATE()) AS age
FROM `users` u
LEFT JOIN `user_basic_info`
    ON user_basic_info.user_id = u.id
WHERE
    (u.`status`=1)
HAVING
    ((age >= 22 && age <= 30))
```

Note that I've edited the `Having` to work more as a 'between', otherwise they don't really do much.

*(i.e. a 13 year old isn't older than 22, but is younger than 30, so is included.  A 99 year old is older than 22 so is also included)*

As a result, making them an `AND` will retrieve anyone between 22 and 30 inclusive.

Comment: "What's the point of a having clause when an and would do?"

Because the `where` clause filters the resultset before a `having` is applied, so there is a performance difference.

Comment: I don't think it's about performance more likely order of execution having comes after select whereas where comes before it so age is visible to having but not to where.

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning an option I missed: using the overloaded `HAVING` clause which _can_ use aliases from the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: "Have you tested this? I thought 'if the GROUP BY clause is omitted, the HAVING clause behaves like the WHERE' so I figured the same issue as using where clause to test age would come into play."

Have you tested it?   You can't use field names in a `HAVING` clause, it will only accept aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use **age** alias  directly in **WHERE** condition for that you have used **HAVING** clause with your  condition.

```
SELECT
    `users`.`nickname`,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,user_basic_info.dob,CURDATE()) AS `age`
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `user_basic_info`
    ON user_basic_info.user_id = users.id
WHERE
    (`users`.`status`=1)
  HAVING  ((TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,user_basic_info.dob,CURDATE())>= 22) OR (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,user_basic_info.dob,CURDATE())<= 30))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `Having` with `age` as follows:

```
SELECT u.nickname,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,ubi.dob,CURDATE()) AS age
FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN user_basic_info as ubi 
ON ubi.user_basic_info.user_id = u.users.id
WHERE u.status = 1 
HAVING
u.age >= 22 OR u.age <= 30
```