# (MYSQL)if another query in where, then the query(another query) operates every row?

Tags: mysql

My query example is :

```
select * from table1 
 where table1_seq = (select table2_seq from table2 where ~)
```

then does sub-query operate every row of table1's Data ??

or

just operates once??

IF once, then which is better performance between upper query or use join query??

Answer (score 0):

With your query it won't return an error only if the subquery return 1 and only 1 result.

You should do an explain on the query :

```
Explain select * from table1 
where table1_seq = (select table2_seq from table2 where id2=X)
```

Will return something like that :

```
id  |   select_type |   table   |   partitions  |   type    |   possible_keys   |   key     |   key_len |   ref     |   rows    |   filtered    |   Extra
==========================================================================================================================================================
1   |   PRIMARY     |   Table1  |   NULL        |   const   |   PRIMARY         |   PRIMARY |   4       |   const   |   1       |   100.00      |   NULL
2   |   SUBQUERY    |   Table2  |   NULL        |   const   |   PRIMARY         |   PRIMARY |   4       |   const   |   1       |   100.00      |   Using index
```

Inner Join in other hand will also do 2 query :

```
EXPLAIN select table1.*
from table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.table1_seq = table2.table2_seq
WHERE  table2.id2=X
```

Result :

```
id  |   select_type |   table   |   partitions  |   type    |   possible_keys   |   key     |   key_len |   ref     |   rows    |   filtered    |   Extra
==========================================================================================================================================================
1   |   SIMPLE      |   Table1  |   NULL        |   const   |   PRIMARY         |   PRIMARY |   4       |   const   |   1       |   100.00      |   NULL
2   |   SIMPLE      |   Table2  |   NULL        |   const   |   PRIMARY         |   PRIMARY |   4       |   const   |   1       |   100.00      |   NULL
```

So it's less a problem of benchmark and more about of what you want to do. If you want to select only 1 value from another table you can really do the query you wrote.

Comment: Thank you for your comment .. and good information but my question is "Does sub-query execute whenever row changed"                                          For example,  table1 has 10 rows Data then the sub query execute 10 times or once ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127932/mysql-query-clause-execution-order , I know only the different clause order execution. Not sure but in my mind the first query will execute on the whole table 1 then narrow with the where statement, in the second query it will restrain on the Join of the 2 tables then narrow the were statement.

Comment: select all data of table1 and where cluase execute like 'inner join'. then,  I think sub-query execute once. i will find more information to be sure. but, your comment gives very helpful concept. Thank you.