# mysql select data from result of alias name on LEFT JOIN condition

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT e.`event_type`,e.`event_status`,er.`event_reg_id`,er.`event_id`,'events' as category, 
    IF(e.`event_type`='C',e.`parent_id` ,IF(e.`event_type`='S',er.`event_id`,'') ) temp_id  
FROM `event_registration` er
    LEFT JOIN event e on er.`event_id`= temp_id WHERE er.`company_id`='%s' AND er.`student_id`='%S'
```

I take `temp_id` as alias name and give it to LEFT JOIN **ON** condition, it not works.
I gave alias name instead of column name on LEFT JOIN ON Condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use the `temp_id` alias on the `ON` part of your query. The alias is not available there. But you can do the following moving the nested `IF` to the `ON` part:

```
SELECT
    e.`event_type`,
    e.`event_status`,
    er.`event_reg_id`,
    er.`event_id`,
    'events' AS category, 
    IF(e.`event_type` = 'C', e.`parent_id`, IF(e.`event_type` = 'S', er.`event_id`,'')) AS temp_id, 
FROM `event_registration` er
    LEFT JOIN event e ON er.`event_id`= IF(e.`event_type` = 'C', e.`parent_id`, IF(e.`event_type` = 'S', er.`event_id`,'')) 
WHERE er.`company_id` = '%s' AND er.`student_id` = '%S'
```

You can't use an alias from `SELECT` because the `FROM` part is executed earlier ([see this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24128128/3840840)).