# SQL Query to select multiple rows with ID

Tags: mysql

I need to select all rows from a table (see structure below) but that's more complex.

I want 5 unique *idm* but all rows with this *idm* (which is the ID of a conversation).. How can I do it ?

```
+------------+
| messagerie |
+------------+
|     ID     |
|    idm     |
|    send    | 
|   receipt  |
|   subject  |
|  message   |
+------------+
```

Comment: `WHERE idm IN (...)` ?

Comment: I don't have any specific idm, i need the last 5 idm from a specific receipt (which is an id of an user).. My topic isn't clear enough..

Comment: show a basic SQL query that you tried so we will be able to try refactor and helping you get working query

Comment: Are you able to get those `idm` ?

Comment: I tried "SELECT * FROM `messagerie` WHERE (SELECT idm FROM messagerie WHERE recept = 0) = messagerie.idm " but this returns multiple rows and wouldn't work..

Comment: @GPerdigal Then, read again my first comment (hint, `IN`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select `distinct` idms for uniqueness and use `LIMIT` keyword to select only `5`.
- Use inner join clause to select all rows who have this `idm`.
- Below query would give you 5 unique `idms` at random all the time.

**SQL:**

```
select *
from messagerie m1
inner join (select distinct idm
              from messagerie
              order by rand() LIMIT 5) m2
on m1.idm = m2.idm;
```

Comment: That sounds perfect.. except that I'm working on a strange SQL server that tells me : #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: @GPerdigal What version of MySQL are you using? Also, I fixed the query from whereIn() to an inner join since it could generate new 5 rows all the time previously.

Comment: @GPerdigal It looks like you could also use whereIn() clause as the order of the execution [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24128128/4964822) here, but better be safe.

Comment: @GPerdigal I suggest you to better upgrade to MariaDB since you would be doing more complex operations as the application scales and you wouldn't want not supported keywords error which are necessary for the task in hand.

Comment: @GPerdigal [This link](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-migrate-from-mysql-to-mariadb-on-linux-in-five-steps/) shall help.