# Understand Mysql execution order (clause)

Tags: mysql

I want to understand how the queries are parsed and get a general view about the query execution order in Mysql

I have a table 'Likes', and I want to find the most liked photo,

this query is ok

```
select photo_id, count(*) as count from likes group by photo_id order by count desc limit 1;
```

but I wanted to know why this query is given me unwanted results, As if I wrote the query without the having clause at the end, a simple count and group by, not executing the max function, or more likely execute it for each distinct row separately:

```
select photo_id,count(*) as count from likes group by photo_id having max(count) ;
```

I read here: [MySQL query / clause execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127932/mysql-query-clause-execution-order) about the execution order, but why can't I use max inside the having clue?

please share with me a good resource on how to understand Mysql queries if you have one :)

Comment: What sort of "unwanted results"?

Comment: As if I wrote the query without the having clause at the end, a simple count and group by, not executing the max function, or more likely execute it for each distinct row separately.

Comment: I think the second query won't be work. will throw an error. because you use aggregate function contain   aggregate function

Comment: `HAVING` is applied after `GROUP BY`, in contrast to `WHERE` which is applied before it. `HAVING` is used to restrict the results returned by `GROUP BY`.

Comment: `having max(count)` and then you miss an operator. That's not how `HAVING` is used, and even if you managed to get it to work - it'd be slower than initial query. Why are you trying to rewrite the first one in the first place? Is it because you're optimizing?

Comment: what you mean with `having max(count)` ?