# Mysql query find replaced column value

Tags: mysql

Hi anyone have idea for finding MySQL row like below code, but this one not working.

I have column value "1205_15_09" and I want to find this row using this condition like 120515

```
SELECT * replace(column_name , '_', '' ) AS new_name 
FROM `table_name` WHERE new_name LIKE '120515%';
```

Comment: Is the data in the column, always going to be in this format: `xxxx_xx_xx` ? If yes, then it would be better to modify the input value to this format, so that you can utilize index on the column. using `Replace()` function on the column, will not use any index at all, and will be extremely inefficient for large tables.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(column_name, '_', '') AS new_value
FROM table_name 
WHERE REPLACE(column_name, '_', '') LIKE '120515%';
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2d8ef8dd0e2ebc0543d08cde9498f9e1)

You can't use the column alias on the `WHERE` part of your query because the `SELECT` part is executed after the `WHERE` part. See the following [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24128128/3840840) describing the query execution order of MySQL.

So you have to use the `REPLACE` on the `WHERE` part. In case you don't need to see / use the `new_value` you can remove the `REPLACE` on `SELECT`.

---

In case the format is always `xxxx_xx_xx`, you can also use a solution like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name 
WHERE column_name LIKE CONCAT(INSERT(INSERT('120515', 5, 0, '_'), 8, 0, '_'), '%');
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b274e97b666dfedb1363f6f1f7a1b406)

As @Madhur Bhaiya already [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57603505/mysql-query-find-replaced-column-value#comment101663614_57603505), you can use a index on the `column_name` to improve the performance on a large table.

Comment: One more doubt, I have a value like 'N-1001-2HO' and I want to find this using numeric pattern like condition column_name = '10012' is possible?

Comment: the numeric part is always in same format? - `N-xxxx-xHO`

Comment: this is one case and it has more patterns like N-xxx, N-xxx-xxx

Comment: @vijinselvaraj - which MySQL version you are using?

Comment: MySQL version 5.6.17

Answer (score 1):

There is also a way with a `HAVING` clause. So there is not need to duplicate the `REPLACE(...)`.

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(column_name, '_', '') AS new_value
FROM table_name 
HAVING new_value LIKE '120515%';
```