# MySQL - How to first JOIN then do WHERE then LIMIT OFFSET

Tags: sql, mysql, join, left-join, limit

For simplicity: having these 3 tables

`my_tickets`

```
+-----------+---------+
| ticket_id | user_id |
+-----------+---------+
| 186       | 2       |
| 187       | 2       |
| 188       | 2       |
| 253       | 33      |
| 254       | 33      |
| 256       | 33      |
| 261       | 33      |
| 262       | 33      |
| 263       | 33      |
| 1573      | 7       |
| 1597      | 7       |
| 1748      | 7       |
+-----------+---------+
```

`my_users`

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
| 2  | user_2  |
| 7  | user_7  |
| 33 | user_33 |
+----+---------+
```

`my_data`

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | ticket_id | data       |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 1  | 186       | data_186_1 |
| 2  | 186       | data_186_2 |
| 3  | 187       | data_187_1 |
| 4  | 253       | data_253_1 |
| 5  | 253       | data_253_2 |
| 6  | 253       | data_253_3 |
| 7  | 254       | data_254_1 |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

**WHAT I NEED: Get data (object like data, not rows) for 3 tickets after the tables were joined & only for user_id=33. I will use this for pagination.**

```
Desired output
+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+
| my_tickets__ticket_id | my_tickets__user_id | my_users__name | my_data__data |
+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+
| 253                   | 33                  | user_33        | data_253_1    |
| 253                   | 33                  | user_33        | data_253_2    |
| 253                   | 33                  | user_33        | data_253_3    |
| 254                   | 33                  | user_33        | data_254_1    |
| 256                   | 33                  | user_33        | NULL          |
+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Please read this article - https://dncrews.com/limit-and-offset-can-work-with-join-f03327fa2ad3

STEPS:

`Step 1: JOIN`
`my_tickets.user_id <=> my_users.id`
`my_tickets.ticket_id <=> my_data.ticket_id)`

```
+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+
| my_tickets__ticket_id | my_tickets__user_id | my_users__name | my_data__data |
+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+
| 186                   | 2                   | user_2         | data_186_1    |
| 186                   | 2                   | user_2         | data_186_2    |
| 187                   | 2                   | user_2         | data_187_1    |
| 188                   | 2                   | user_2         | NULL          |
| 1573                  | 7                   | user_7         | NULL          |
| 1597                  | 7                   | user_7         | NULL          |
| 1748                  | 7                   | user_7         | NULL          |
| 253                   | 33                  | user_33        | data_253_1    |
| 253                   | 33                  | user_33        | data_253_2    |
| 253                   | 33                  | user_33        | data_253_3    |
| 254                   | 33                  | user_33        | data_254_1    |
| 256                   | 33                  | user_33        | NULL          |
| 261                   | 33                  | user_33        | NULL          |
| 262                   | 33                  | user_33        | NULL          |
| 263                   | 33                  | user_33        | NULL          |
+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

`Step 2: WHERE (my_tickets.user_id = 33)`

```
+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+
| my_tickets__ticket_id | my_tickets__user_id | my_users__name | my_data__data |
+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+
| 253                   | 33                  | user_33        | data_253_1    |
| 253                   | 33                  | user_33        | data_253_2    |
| 253                   | 33                  | user_33        | data_253_3    |
| 254                   | 33                  | user_33        | data_254_1    |
| 256                   | 33                  | user_33        | NULL          |
| 261                   | 33                  | user_33        | NULL          |
| 262                   | 33                  | user_33        | NULL          |
| 263                   | 33                  | user_33        | NULL          |
+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

`Step 3: LIMIT (limit the result to 3 tickets (object kind))`

```
+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+
| my_tickets__ticket_id | my_tickets__user_id | my_users__name | my_data__data |
+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+
| 253                   | 33                  | user_33        | data_253_1    |
| 253                   | 33                  | user_33        | data_253_2    |
| 253                   | 33                  | user_33        | data_253_3    |
| 254                   | 33                  | user_33        | data_254_1    |
| 256                   | 33                  | user_33        | NULL          |
+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

**WHAT I TRIED:**

`Query`
I expected this query to output 3 results (as in Step 3) after the tables were joined & only for user_id=33, but the output is empty

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        my_tickets.ticket_id AS my_tickets__ticket_id, my_tickets.user_id AS my_tickets__user_id,
        my_users.name AS my_users__name, my_data.data AS my_data__data
    FROM my_tickets
    
    LEFT JOIN my_users ON my_tickets.user_id=my_users.id 
    LEFT JOIN my_data ON my_tickets.ticket_id=my_data.ticket_id 

    WHERE my_tickets.user_id = 33

) as t1

    WHERE
    
    t1.my_tickets__ticket_id IN (
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT ticket_id FROM my_tickets LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0
        ) as t2
    )

OUTPUT: Empty table
```

---

**UPDATE**:
Answering lemon's statement: I over-complicated things by using subquery for a reason. I need to use LIMIT OFFSET for pagination of the content. And MySQL is applying the LIMIT on the number of rows returned, on the other hand I need to apply LIMIT on the object-like data. Why object like data? => I updated the tables in initial question to reflect that (added my_data table)
Based on this article - https://dncrews.com/limit-and-offset-can-work-with-join-f03327fa2ad3

Comment: Please put all & only what is needed to ask in your post, Quote with credit & relate to your post. Don't expect readers to read entire other pages or guess what is relevant & why. Please use code  format for code. Please don't YELL.

Comment: This post lines up a where with its select/from, yet indents other wheres from their select/from. Please pick one style. PS Just vertically aligning query clause keywords (and usually ONs) minimizes indentation. Indenting clauses of a query doesn't add clarification & makes it harder to find the clauses that form a query.

Comment: This doesn't clearly say how output is a function of input. Don't expect us to guess from 1 (too  big) example. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS If you do not say what you expect & why & justify per competent documentation, you ask us to (re)write yet another presentation of the language, with no details on what you misunderstand or do or don't understand.

Comment: Queries return rows. What do you mean by *object like data, not rows*?

Comment: @forpas: for user_id=33 would like to get 5 rows (see "Desired output"). Those 5 rows are actually 3 object elements (for ticket_id: 253, 254, 256)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get distinct users and tickets limiting to 3 then join

```
select s.*,md.*,mu.name from
(select distinct user_id,ticket_id from my_tickets mt  where user_id = 33 limit 3) s
left join my_data md on md.ticket_id = s.ticket_id
join my_users mu on mu.id = s.user_id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/eloidh90

Comment: thanks for the idea [first do WHERE (my_tickets) => then LIMIT (my_tickets) => then JOIN (other tables)]
I applied that to my real life tables and looks like it works!

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be overcomplicating things. You can do it without subqueries:

```
SELECT t.ticket_id,
       t.user_id,
       u.name
FROM       mytickets t
INNER JOIN myusers u ON t.user_id = u.id
WHERE user_id = 33
LIMIT 3
```

This holds the correct result because the following activate in the given order:

1. `FROM` clause
2. `WHERE` clause
3. `SELECT` clause
4. `LIMIT` clause

Here you can get a [thorough discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127932/mysql-query-clause-execution-order) on execution order among clauses, or you can go on the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html).

Additionally, note that the output is not deterministic, as you don't know the order in which data is stored inside the database. The only way to retrieve your three rows deterministically is by using an `ORDER BY` clause, able to impose an order among your rows and break potential ties.

**Output**:

| ticket_id | user_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 253 | 33 | user_33 |
| 254 | 33 | user_33 |
| 256 | 33 | user_33 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3MTX8wjoNrCbyuREfjKrHZ/0).

---

**Update**: What if I want to limit object-like data to a specified amount?

Don't use `LIMIT`, as it brings unnecessary complexity and it becomes very difficult to handle.

You can instead apply filtering over the output of [`DENSE_RANK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) ranking window function. It will assign an identifier to each record of your object-like rows, which you can apply filtering on.

Here's an example:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.ticket_id,
           t.user_id,
           u.name,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY user_id) AS rn
    FROM       mytickets t
    INNER JOIN myusers u ON t.user_id = u.id
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 3
```

This query will allow you to pick all records from the last three user_id values, which is not the last three records only.

Comment: There's no real sequence of steps in SQL since it's a declarative language. However, that explanation can be useful as a conceptual idea of how it could work.

Comment: @lemon I appreciate your time answering my question. However I didn't describe well my case. I just updated the post with more details. Kindly please check it. Thank you

Comment: In order to solve that problem, you can avoid using the `LIMIT ... OFFSET` clause, and use a `DENSE_RANK` window function, that assigns a ranking value to each object you need. Then, after having stored the output inside a subquery, a `WHERE` clause will help you filter out the amount of "objects" you don't need.

Comment: @lemon - interesting idea! Thanks! I will look into this, never used it. It would help a lot if you can update your fiddle with DENSE_RANK.

Comment: I'm still not sure how the example in your post would fit the `LIMIT OFFSET` idea, but I've updated my answer with an example of what I meant.

Comment: @lemon thanks! Is it possible to simulate OFFSET functionality with DENSE_RANK ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I explain in the updated answer.

Comment: @lemon: looks like CTE is not available in MySQL 5.7...

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to update your version if you can. There are lots of limitations with legacy versions of MySQL, including `LIMIT ... OFFSET` as the only possible way, with some complex workarounds involving either variables or dynamic queries.

Comment: @lemon is there a way to use DENSE_RANK without CTE?

Comment: DENSE_RANK is not available in MySQL 5.7, you shall go through a `LIMIT OFFSET` solution is that is the environment.

Comment: @lemon: can't upgrade to 8, so I am stuck with 5.7. Would highly appreciate if you can suggest a solution using LIMIT OFFSET clause..