Group by and having clause
Consider the following relational schema:
candidates (candidate_id, skill)

[Sample input table]
Select candidate_id
from candidates 
group by candidate_id
having sum(if(lower(skill)='python' or lower(skill)='tableau',1,0))=3

How can we even access a cell in the having clause by using aggregate functions?
As we know the having is executed after group by, hence the data should be lost while summarising?
What am I missing out?
I know having clause executes after group by, hence when group by executes the rows/records are summarised, the data present in the cells should be lost? We should not be able to access it however possible even by aggregate functions ?

Please publish images as text. To be honest I won't see understand what you expect to happen..

What exactly is the question? The query in the question does not work and and you would like to make it work? Or the query in the question works and you are wondering why?

@Shadow Yes, The query works & I am wondering how the having clause is executing here internally, like how are we even being able to access the data after it is summarise by group by.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127932/mysql-query-clause-execution-order is I think what you should be researching.

As the having section of mysql manual on select statement says:

The HAVING clause can refer to aggregate functions, which the WHERE clause cannot

The having clause of your sql statement refers to aggregate functions, so it is in line with mysql manual. I do understand why you raised the question as the conditional expression in the aggregate function means that mysql needs row-level access to the underlying data. But mysql needs row-level access if the aggregate function is not part of select list as well.
